# NameError: global name 'on_connect' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, mqtt

```
class HasadCoreManager:

    # The callback for when the client receives a connect response from the server.
    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
        print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
        client.subscribe(constants.MQTT_PATH_SUBSCRIBE)
        client.message_callback_add("hasadNode/water", on_message())
        client.message_callback_add("hasadNode/air", on_message())
```

when I call the function on_connect in the startingLooping function which is a function inside the same class on the same level like this :

```
def startLooping(self):
    print("Core Just started...")
    client = mqtt.Client()
    print("MQTT Client initialized")
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.connect(constants.MQTT_SERVER, 1883, 60)
    client.loop_start()
```

i get the error : NameError: global name 'on_connect' is not defined

what to do to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

in `startLooping`, you write

```
client.on_connect = on_connect
```

which looks for the name `on_connect` in the global namespace.
You want to use the `on_connect` method of HasadCoreManager, therefore it should be

```
client.on_connect = self.on_connect
```

I can imagine you will get a similar error for the uses of `on_message`

Answer (score 1):

Your on_connect function doesn't need to be part of a class. But if you want it to be that way then it should be a static method. Then:

```
class HasadCoreManager:
    # The callback for when the client receives a connect response from the server.
    @staticmethod
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
        client.subscribe(constants.MQTT_PATH_SUBSCRIBE)
        client.message_callback_add("hasadNode/water", on_message())
        client.message_callback_add("hasadNode/air", on_message())
```

Notice how the method signature has changed. Then:

```
def startLooping(self):
    print("Core Just started...")
    client = mqtt.Client()
    print("MQTT Client initialized")
    client.on_connect = HasadCoreManager.on_connect
    #you will probably want something similar here
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.connect(constants.MQTT_SERVER, 1883, 60)
    client.loop_start()
```